# MatPlotLib create labels in the legend from the df

Tags: python, matplotlib, line, legend

I have created multipleline plot that shows data about different plants.
Right now the legend is based on  index of numbers that was creates as defult.
I would like the labels to be based on a column that contains the plant names (that called ('plants')

I have tried to this this like that:

```
new_db.iloc[:,2:].T.plot(figsize=(17,10),label=[new_db['plant']]);
```

But I have still gotten the numbers as the labels:

[image]

My goal is to have the legend with the names of the plants

Edit: This is how the table looks like:
[image]

Comment: please post some of your orginal data

Comment: @warped2 I can't post my data but I can show what iss the structure

Comment: did you try - plt.legend(new_db['plant'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need is simply to do -

```
plt.legend(new_db['plant'])
```

It should work with your legend problem, however if it doesn`t. Please add more info and code on what you have tried and I will edit this answer.